# Como transformar esse comando Curl / PUT em php?

Tags: php, libcurl

Como devo proceder para transpor esse código curl para enviá-lo em um arquivo PHP?

```
curl -X PUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/json" -d
{
  "status":"paused"
}
https://api.mercadolibre.com/items/ITEM_ID?access_token=YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

Comment: não é a mesma coisa...

Comment: isso por exemplo não precisa na requisição put: "curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);"

Comment: estou com dificuldades na criação do corpo da requisição: header , data (como enviar via json), etc; Não sei como fica a sintaxe...

Comment: Bom, reabri, mas se seguir a lógica de lá (assim como o link que aponta para todas as opções do cURL), acho que você consegue com facilidade. Eu tenho a impressão que vai ser mais rápido do que esperar alguém pegar exatamente a sua requisição e adaptar, mas de qq forma, está aberta.

Comment: Headers: curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array( 'header1: valor1', 'header2: valor2' ));

Comment: Poderia descomplicar usando a library oficial: https://github.com/mercadolibre/php-sdk

Answer (score 4):

```
$url       = 'https://api.mercadolibre.com/items/ITEM_ID?access_token=YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN';
$cabecalho = array('Content-Type: application/json', 'Accept: application/json');
$campos    = json_encode(array('status' => 'paused'));

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,            $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,     $cabecalho);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,     $campos);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,           true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST,  'PUT');

$resposta = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Seria realmente necessário (ou aconselhável) setar `CURLOPT_POST`?

Answer (score -1):

Solução perfeita funciona perfeitamente so esqueceu do ponto e virgula

```
$url       = 'https://api.mercadolibre.com/items/ITEM_ID?access_token=YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN';
$cabecalho = array('Content-Type: application/json', 'Accept: application/json')    <<<<--------   adicionar o   ";"
$campos    = json_encode(array('status' => 'paused'));

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,            $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,     $cabecalho);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,     $campos);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,           true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST,  'PUT');

$resposta = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
```